# How do I set up Minecraft on split screen for Playstation 3?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Me and my friend want to play Minecraft on the same PS3, but I don't know how to set up split screen.

How can I play split-screen on Minecraft for my Playstation 3?

Answer (score 1):

Create a world and uncheck the Online game checkbox.  Then, start the game.  With the second controller, the other player should be able to sign in using another account on the PS3.

[The Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Splitscreen) shows how to do this (for the Xbox 360, though the process should be the same for PS3).

Note you need to be on a 720p resolution or be using an HDMI cable.